# Mysterious Short Hostile Phone Conversation in Training Day

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, training-day

When Alonzo Harris along with Jake Hoyt went to visit Roger the first time, the latter receives a phone call where he said "it's your mess, you clean it up".

What's the purpose of this phone call?